# Windows Home 7 and virtualization

Tags: virtualization

so apparently, you can't use VirtualBox etc with Windows Home 7. because you would be using two licenses instead of one.

So other users that tried virtualization with Windows Home Premium 7, did you just end up using another OS like Ubuntu etc? Did you find a workaround for using Windows?

When I say virtualization, I mean virtual machine of sort - where dangerous websites can be visited, nasty applications can be tried etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, to run two copies of Windows Home 7 you need two licences, no matter if the installations are virtual or physical.

So you could purchase another copy, or as you suggest, install linux as the host operating system and run Windows virtualised.

Answer (score 3):

You are able to use Visualization on Windows 7 Home Premium. You do not get access to the Windows [XP/Visualization mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) that is provided by Windows. You should not have any issue using Virtualbox at all.

You can run any operating system you wish in VirtualBox, but by the End-User Agreement, you need 2 copies of Windows to run it in VirtualBox.